# Changing the header image using WPML

Tags: functions, plugin-wpml

I've got an issue with changing a header image based on language and the file path to the image. Have tried relative and absolute paths but still end up with a broken/missing file icon.

In my functions I have:

```
function header_image_switcher() {
    switch( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ) {

        case 'en':
            $link_to_image = '/images/top-header-en.png';
            break;

        case 'fi':
            $link_to_image = '/images/top-header-fi.png';
            break;

        case 'sv':
            $link_to_image = '/images/top-header-sv.png';
            break;

        return $link_to_image;
    }
}
```

and the template contains

```
echo "<img src=" . header_image_switcher() . " />";
```

My images folder is outside of the theme and in the same folder as my install but the images still won't load.

Any obvious mistakes I'm making?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML? Is `src` empty or just pointing somewhere wrong?

Comment: Your image folder is _inside the WordPress root directory_ ? So `wp-load.php` and your `images` folder are at the same place?

Comment: Hi...the source comes back empty...just a backslash.

Kaiser, yes this the current directory setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`site_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/site_url/) or `get_site_url()`. Depending on your install and setup, you could as well use [`network_site_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/network_site_url/) - which is what I would prefer as it falls back to `site_url()` internally if it is no multisite setup.

The `site_url( $path, $scheme );` function also takes two arguments:

1. The `$path` can be used to append a path to the URl in case you need to point somewhere custom.
2. Omit the second one, as it's the `scheme` (http/s) and will be set automatically - only use it if you want to force a scheme.

---

Note: You might want to make your `switch` a bit more fail save:

```
switch ( $foo )
{
    case 'bar' :
        return 'I am bar';
        break;

    case default :
    case 'baz' :
        return 'I am baz';
        break;
}
```

Having a `default` will save you from failing when none of the conditions are met - with language you might want to use American English. Also you can `return` immediately as there is nothing which shall happen with the `switch` result afterwards.